# Laravel artisan make:auth

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I am new to Laravel 5 and I am wanting to create an "admin" area so I have created `views/admin` and `controllers/admin` folders.  Is there a way using artisan or make:auth that will allow me to specify the "folder" that I would like the code to be installed into?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command itself doesn't allow you to do that, however you can change paths for your auth routes, controllers and views manually. It's really easy to do that. Just don't forget also to edit `namespace` in you controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\MyAdminPanel;
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the path with artisan command like this :

```
php artisan make:controller Admin\\AdminController
```

it will create Admin folder in Controllers folder and in side it AdminController file

for views you have to set it manually